# SpatialDepthWiseConvolution Xception backpropagation error

Tags: lua, neural-network, deep-learning, torch

I'm trying to implement NN inspired by Xception ideas.
Can't understand what is wrong with my model...

```
local torch = require 'torch'
local nn = require 'nn'

dofile('GlobalAveragePooling.lua')

local model = nn.Sequential()
-- Entry convolution 
model:add( nn.SpatialConvolution(3, 64, 3, 3, 2, 2, 1, 1) )
model:add( nn.SpatialBatchNormalization(64) )
model:add( nn.ReLU() )

-- Xception Unit with "skip-path"
local seq = nn.Sequential()
seq:add( nn.SpatialDepthWiseConvolution(64, 1, 3, 3, 1, 1, 1, 1) )
seq:add( nn.SpatialConvolution(64, 512, 1, 1, 1, 1, 0, 0) )
seq:add( nn.SpatialBatchNormalization(512) )
seq:add( nn.SpatialMaxPooling(3, 3, 2, 2, 1, 1) )

local con = nn.ConcatTable()
con:add( nn.SpatialConvolution(64, 512, 1, 1, 2, 2, 0, 0) )
con:add( seq )

model:add( con )
model:add( nn.CAddTable() )
model:add( nn.ReLU() )

-- Exit fully-connected layers for softmax(3) output
model:add( nn.GlobalAveragePooling() )
model:add( nn.Reshape(512) )

model:add( nn.Linear(512, 3) )
model:add( nn.LogSoftMax() )

print(tostring(model))

local X = torch.randn(10, 3, 16, 8)
local Y = torch.LongTensor(10):random(1,3)

local criterion = nn.ClassNLLCriterion()

local Yhat = model:forward(X)

local loss = criterion:forward(Yhat, Y)
local gradLoss = criterion:backward(Yhat, Y)
model:backward(X, gradLoss)
```

The model works good at forward() step.
But fails when it comes to model:backward(X, gradLoss) with error:

```
    /nn/THNN.lua:110: Need gradOutput of dimension 5 and gradOutput.size[3] == 8 but got gradOutput to be of shape: [10 x 64 x 1 x 4 x 8] at ../THNN/generic/SpatialDepthWiseConvolution.c:53
stack traceback:
[C]: in function 'v'    ../nn/THNN.lua:110: in function 'SpatialDepthWiseConvolution_updateGradInput'   ../nn/SpatialDepthWiseConvolution.lua:80:
in function 'updateGradInput' ../Module.lua:31:
in function <../nn/Module.lua:29>
[C]: in function 'xpcall'   ../nn/Container.lua:63:
in function 'rethrowErrors'     ../nn/Sequential.lua:88:
in function <../nn/Sequential.lua:78>
[C]: in function 'xpcall'   ../Container.lua:63:
in function 'rethrowErrors'     ../nn/ConcatTable.lua:66:
in function <../ConcatTable.lua:30>
[C]: in function 'xpcall'   ../nn/Container.lua:63:
in function 'rethrowErrors'     ../nn/Sequential.lua:84:
in function 'backward'  test.lua:45:
in main chunk   [C]: at 0x00405d50
```

Comment: After some investigation I've narrowed down the problem to SpatialDepthWiseConvolution implementation in torch. See issue here:
https://github.com/torch/nn/issues/1307

Answer (score 0):

As it turned out, the problem is in low-level implementation of SpatialDepthWiseConvolution in torch/nn. I've created an issue: https://github.com/torch/nn/issues/1307

For the moment (03 of March 2018) this issue is not solved yet.
Of course, I hope that somebody will fix mistake in low-level implementation.
But for now I know two ways to overcome this problem:

- emulate via torch containers
- use my pure-lua implementation

Here is a way to emulate this module using containers **Concat** and **Parallel** along with standard **SpatialConvolution** module:

```
  local depth_wise_conv = nn.Concat(2)
  for o = 1, nOutputPlane do
    local out = nn.Parallel(2, 2)
    for i = 1, nInputPlane do
      local seq = nn.Sequential()
      local conv = nn.SpatialConvolution(1, 1, kW, kH, dW, dH, pW, pH):noBias()
      seq:add( nn.Reshape(1, inputHeight, inputWidth) )
      seq:add( conv )
      out:add( seq )
    end
    depth_wise_conv:add( out )
  end
```

Note that depth_wise_conv module in the code above is supposed to get batch-input with 4 dimensions: `batchSize x nInputPlane x inputHeight x inputWidth`.

But I also spend some time and created a pure-lua implementation of **SpatialDepthWiseConvolution** as a module. You may find it here:
https://gist.github.com/diovisgood/36ce5a6c5e9dd4cb20b13dd2a28c1f71

There are also: **SpatialConvolution** implementation and unit tests.
I published these modules under MIT license, so anyone can use them.

Please note that these modules have not been heavily tested!
So any help or advice is appreciated.

One more thing. There is a great paper that explains convolution and transposed convolution by Vincent Dumoulin and Francesco Visin:
['A guide to convolution arithmetic for deep learning'](https://arxiv.org/pdf/1603.07285.pdf)